# «По всей видимости» — особенности пунктуации

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

> Носильщик с сомнением покосился на её петлицы рядового третьего
>   разряда, но всё же побежал в вагон, по всей видимости рассудив, что
>   если у рядовой вольняшки хватило денег на билет в первый класс, то
>   наверняка хватит и на носильщика.

*По всей видимости рассудив* — нужна ли запятая между *видимости* и *рассудив*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**По всей видимости**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_529) — это вводное сочетание, которое выделяется (или отделяется) запятыми.

Однако есть такая особенность:
если вводное сочетание стоит **в начале** обособленного оборота — запятые ставятся **перед** вводным сочетанием и **после** всего обособленного оборота; после вводного сочетания запятая **не ставится** (иначе говоря, «закрывающая» запятая переносится в конец обособленного оборота).
[Пунктуация при вводных словах и сочетаниях](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach2)

В Вашем предложении вводное сочетание стоит перед одиночным деепричастием, требующим обособления, — запятая между *видимости* и *рассудив* не требуется.

*— Старый хранитель канул в небытие, **по всей видимости исполнив** просьбу неизвестного доброжелателя до конца, – рассказчик грустно усмехнулся* (П. Блэк).

*Примерно в таком духе проходил наш разговор с Венди, и она, **по всей видимости надеясь** на откровенность, сделала мне щедрое предложение...* (Б. А. Бейкер)

*— Как вы себя чувствуете? – спросила девушка, **по всей видимости стараясь** знакомыми фразами скрыть свое смущени*е (В. Сорокин).

Answer (score 2):

*Носильщик с сомнением покосился на её петлицы рядового третьего разряда, но всё же побежал в вагон, **по всей видимости рассудив**, что если у рядовой вольняшки хватило денег на билет в первый класс, то наверняка хватит и на носильщика.*

Если вводное слово или сочетание стоит в начале или в конце обособленного оборота, то оно от оборота не отделяется. У нас вводное сочетание в начале деепричастия - запятая не нужна.